# Google Drive API Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I successfully completed the quickstart shows HERE:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python

I wish to go further and begin to upload files and folders.   To do so I have replaced the scope with:
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

I have also replaced the execution with

```
national_parks = ['Yellowstone', 'Rocky Mountain', 'Yosemite']

for national_park in national_parks:
    file_metadata = {'name': national_park,
                     'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
                     # 'parents': []

                     }
    service.files().create(body=file_metadata).execute()
```

I then get an error:
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">

Help please

Comment: When changing the scopes, have you deleted the `token.pickle` file?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like your scopes might not be correct, replace with the following:

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

Comment: Thanks for your reply!   Unfortunately pasting the above snippet still creates the error listed above :(

Comment: If you haven't looked through it I would check through: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing

Just to ensure there isn't an issue with your access token and you are requesting the appropriate scopes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the scopes to one of the following

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

and delete the token.pickle file, it will then prompt you to authorize the application again this time with the required scope of permissions needed to call that method

Comment: Awesome! I updated the permissions, but it didn't work until I deleted the token.pickle file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not only must change the scope to the
[appropriate scope URL](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes)
but also delete 'token.json' file and then create new token.
Basically by running the code it will automatically create new token with the correct scope

Answer (score 0):

- 1: delete the file: `token.json`
- 2: chose correct scope like:  [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive]
- Ref: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes

[image: list of scopes with one boxed in red]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).