# Airflow 2.0 GoogleDriveHook upload_file: insufficient authentication scopes

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth, airflow

I'm trying to use the Airflow 2.0 `GoogleDriveHook` to upload a local file to my Google Workspace's Drive. I'm not familiar with OAuth 2.0.

I took the following steps:

#### In GCP I:

- Created `airflow-drive` project on GCP
- Enabled the Google Drive API for this project
- Created the `airflow-drive-service-account` service account and gave it the (project) "Owner" and "Service Account Token Creator" roles.
- Created a json-key for `airflow-drive-service-account`

#### In Airflow I:

- Created the Airflow Connection `airflow-drive` and specified the path of the json-key
- Wrote the following code to test the `upload_file` method:

```py
from airflow.providers.google.suite.hooks.drive import GoogleDriveHook

hook = GoogleDriveHook(
    api_version='v3',
    gcp_conn_id='airflow-drive',
    delegate_to=None,
    impersonation_chain=None
)

hook.upload_file(
    local_location='some_file.txt',
    remote_location='/some_file.txt'
)
```

This is the error I receive upon running the script:

```
[2021-01-26 10:01:08,286] {http.py:126} WARNING - Encountered 403 Forbidden with reason "insufficientPermissions"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_drive_hook.py", line 11, in <module>
    hook.upload_file(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/suite/hooks/drive.py", line 144, in upload_file
    service.files()  # pylint: disable=no-member
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 915, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?fields=id&alt=json&uploadType=multipart returned "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">
```

### Questions:

1. I don't understand where I have to configure the authentication scopes. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64508018/google-drive-api-insufficient-permission-request-had-insufficient-authenticatio) talks about defining scopes using a SCOPES variable. But I'm not sure how I should do this for Airflow / Google Drive API.
2. It's unclear whether I have to use the `delegate_to` and/or `impersonation_chain` parameters for my use case. [This Airflow issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/9461) touches this subject but doesn't clarify whether I need Domain-Wide Delegation for my use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, the issue has been solved.

Here is the solution:

My approach above was correct. I just needed to add the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` scope in the Scopes field in the Airflow Connection:

[image]